# Uninstalling SQL Server 2012, No option to select instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

[image]Hi I am currently trying to completly remove sql server 2012 from my machine, when I click uninstall from the control panel then > remove, I have no option to select and instance to remove and i've no idea why.

Comment: Did you try with 'Select All' Button option.

Answer (score 3):

When you deinstall SQL Server you have to select the correct program in the "Progams & features" windows. (appwiz.cpl)

[image: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)]

> Hint: It should be the program with no size.

Start the program and you should be guided through the de-installation routine.

If you don't see any option to de-install an instance, then you might not be running the correct program version, or you might not be on the server you are trying to de-install the SQL Server instance from.

Comment: Thank you - in my case I had both the 32 and 64-bit options with no size, but only uninstalling from the 64-bit entry allowed uninstalling of the instance.